# Can jQuery Quicksearch be configured to only return exact matches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, exact-match, quick-search

I'm using [jQuery Quicksearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.quicksearch) and am wondering if there is a way to adjust it to only return exact matches for the search. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean full-string matches?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) of jquery quicksearch plugin, it seems that you could use the `testQuery` option to define a function that tells if an item should be hidden or not:

> **testQuery** Function that tells if a given item should be hidden. It takes 3 arguments:
>
> - query prepared by 'prepareQuery'
> - stripped text from 'selector'
> - element to be potentially hidden

It seems that the `query` param received in the `testQuery` method is an array though. So we can grab the first item of the array (which is the text introduced in the input) or we can use the `prepareQuery` option to return the query as it is (a string):

```
prepareQuery: function(val) {
    return val;
}
```

Now that we have the query param as a string, if you want an exact match you could try using `testQuery` with something like:

```
testQuery: function (query, txt, _row) {
    return query === txt;
}
```

With these two options we would be comparing the input text (which is the `query` parameter in `testQuery`) with all the text of the row (including all cells, which is the `txt` parameter in `testQuery`).

If we want to match the exact text in any cell, we need to define that in the `selector` option.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1uo7djf/) that matches by email column (that's because we are passing the *selector* option equal to `th`). Take into account that the rows will only be showed when the introduced text matches exactly with the cell content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `prepareQuery` method to match against the full string with `'prepareQuery': function (val) { return new RegExp("^" + val + "$", "i"); }`

```js
$('input#id_search2').quicksearch('table#table_example2 tbody tr', {
  'delay': 300,
  'selector': 'th',
  'stripeRows': ['odd', 'even'],
  'loader': 'span.loading',
  'bind': 'keyup click input',
  'show': function () {
    this.style.color = '';
  },
  'hide': function () {
    this.style.color = '#ccc';
  },
  'prepareQuery': function (val) {
    return new RegExp("^" + val + "$", "i");
  },
  'testQuery': function (query, txt, _row) {
    return query.test(txt);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.quicksearch/2.4.0/jquery.quicksearch.min.js"></script>
<h3>Example with options — search with email regexp on &lt;th&gt; only</h3>

<form action="#">
 <fieldset>
  <input name="search" value="devo" id="id_search2" type="text"> <span class="loading" style="display: none;">Loading...</span>
 </fieldset>
</form>

<table id="table_example2">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th width="30%">Email</th>
   <th width="10%">Id</th>
   <th width="10%">Phone</th>
   <th width="10%">Total</th>
   <th width="10%">Ip</th>
   <th width="10%">Url</th>
   <th width="10%">Time</th>
   <th width="10%">ISO Date</th>
   <th width="10%">UK Date</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="odd">
   <th>devo@flexomat.com</th>

   <td>66672</td>
   <td>941-964-8535</td>
   <td>$2482.79</td>
   <td>172.78.200.124</td>

   <td>http://gmail.com</td>
   <td>15:10</td>

   <td>1988/12/14</td>
   <td>14/12/1988</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>henry@mountdev.net</th>

   <td>35889</td>

   <td>941-964-9543</td>
   <td>$2776.09</td>
   <td>119.232.182.142</td>
   <td>http://www.gmail.com</td>
   <td>3:54</td>

   <td>1974/1/19</td>

   <td>19/1/1974</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="odd" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>christian@reno.gov</th>
   <td>60021</td>
   <td>941-964-5617</td>

   <td>$2743.41</td>
   <td>167.209.64.181</td>
   <td>http://www.dotnet.ca</td>
   <td>10:58</td>
   <td>2000/3/25</td>
   <td>25/3/2000</td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="even" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>muffins@donuts.com</th>
   <td>17927</td>
   <td>941-964-9511</td>
   <td>$2998.18</td>

   <td>210.214.231.182</td>

   <td>http://google.se</td>
   <td>21:22</td>
   <td>1993/1/24</td>
   <td>24/1/1993</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="odd" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>muffins@reno.gov</th>

   <td>76375</td>
   <td>941-964-2757</td>
   <td>$1836.09</td>
   <td>220.222.93.171</td>

   <td>http://www.samba.org</td>
   <td>15:22</td>

   <td>1988/4/4</td>
   <td>4/4/1988</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">

   <th>mendez@gmail.com</th>
   <td>45834</td>
   <td>941-964-2575</td>

   <td>$2805.46</td>
   <td>228.170.245.253</td>
   <td>http://flexomat.com</td>

   <td>11:31</td>
   <td>1975/12/12</td>
   <td>12/12/1975</td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="odd" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>dev@gmail.com</th>

   <td>20022</td>
   <td>941-964-4967</td>
   <td>$3296.54</td>
   <td>175.248.70.240</td>

   <td>http://www.flexomat.com</td>
   <td>4:27</td>

   <td>2002/7/3</td>
   <td>3/7/2002</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>foo@polyester.se</th>

   <td>55977</td>

   <td>941-964-745</td>
   <td>$2953.73</td>
   <td>222.114.227.156</td>
   <td>http://www.donuts.com</td>
   <td>23:49</td>

   <td>1977/8/4</td>

   <td>4/8/1977</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="odd" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>adam@aftonbladet.se</th>
   <td>38867</td>
   <td>941-964-6302</td>

   <td>$1949.27</td>
   <td>116.241.143.196</td>
   <td>http://flexomat.com</td>
   <td>23:35</td>
   <td>1995/7/27</td>
   <td>27/7/1995</td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="even">
   <th>devo@donuts.com</th>
   <td>51426</td>
   <td>941-964-1234</td>
   <td>$1067.00</td>

   <td>88.96.149.82</td>

   <td>http://www.polyester.se</td>
   <td>15:17</td>
   <td>1986/1/5</td>
   <td>5/1/1986</td>
  </tr>


  <tr class="odd" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>henry@samba.org</th>

   <td>40859</td>
   <td>941-964-4856</td>
   <td>$3401.19</td>
   <td>68.152.250.74</td>

   <td>http://www.flexomat.com</td>
   <td>4:36</td>

   <td>1990/3/7</td>
   <td>7/3/1990</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">

   <th>found@dotnet.ca</th>
   <td>23986</td>
   <td>941-964-2686</td>

   <td>$1393.52</td>
   <td>98.102.181.138</td>
   <td>http://lostnfound.org</td>

   <td>5:51</td>
   <td>1993/7/22</td>
   <td>22/7/1993</td>

  </tr>

  <tr class="odd" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>carl@fish.org</th>

   <td>73392</td>
   <td>941-964-5792</td>
   <td>$3876.04</td>
   <td>246.234.182.243</td>

   <td>http://www.google.se</td>
   <td>6:52</td>

   <td>1984/7/14</td>
   <td>14/7/1984</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="even" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   <th>found@mountdev.net</th>

   <td>03519</td>

   <td>941-964-1599</td>
   <td>$1176.48</td>
   <td>104.212.122.177</td>
   <td>http://donutsx.com</td>
   <td>18:52</td>

   <td>2000/8/6</td>

   <td>6/8/2000</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody></table>
```